# How to debug a lambda calculus evaluator which only partially reduces lambda terms?

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, interpreter, lambda-calculus

I'm struggling to figure out why my evaluator won't work on the untyped lambda calculus. Here is a counterexample to its evaluation: note >= 3 applications of eval results in the correct answer, but as soon as we run the evaluator just once we get only a partially evaluated form.  I don't know how to test/decide where/how the evaluator is improperly defined (perhaps it's in one of the other functions?)

```
*Main> eval $ eval $ eval $ eval num10
Lam "f" (Lam "x" (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f"
) (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f") (Var "x"))))))))))))
*Main> eval $ eval $ eval num10
Lam "f" (Lam "x" (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f"
) (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f") (App (Var "f") (Var "x"))))))))))))
*Main> eval $ eval  num10
Lam "f" (Lam "x" (App (Var "f") (App (Lam "x" (App (Var "f") (App (Lam "x" (App (Var "f") (App (Lam "x" (App (Var "f") (
App (Lam "x" (App (Var "f") (App (Lam "x" (App (Var "f") (App (Lam "x" (App (Var "f") (App (Lam "x" (App (Var "f") (App 
(Lam "x" (App (Var "f") (App (Lam "x" (App (Var "f") (Var "x"))) (Var "x")))) (Var "x")))) (Var "x")))) (Var "x")))) (Va
r "x")))) (Var "x")))) (Var "x")))) (Var "x")))) (Var "x"))))
```

The remaining code is below

```
import Data.List

type Name = String

data Expr
  = Var Name
  | App Expr Expr
  | Lam Name Expr
  deriving (Show,Eq)

add = Lam "m" (Lam "n" (Lam "f" (Lam "x"
          (App (App (Var "m") (Var "f"))
               (App (App (Var "n") (Var "f"))
                    (Var "x"))))))

suc = Lam "n" (Lam "f" (Lam "x" 
          (App (Var "f") 
               (App (App (Var "n") (Var "f"))
                    (Var "x")))))

num0  = Lam "f" (Lam "x" (Var "x"))
num1  = App suc num0
num2  = App suc num1
num3  = App suc num2
num4  = App suc num3
num5  = App suc num4
num6  = App suc num5
num7  = App suc num6
num8  = App suc num7
num9  = App suc num8
num10 = App suc num9

fv (Var x) = [x]
fv (Lam x e) = delete x (fv e)
fv (App e1 e2) = union (fv e1) (fv e2)

rename x y (Var z)
  | x == z = Var y
  | otherwise = Var z
rename x y (Lam z e)
  | x == z = Lam y (rename x y e)
  | otherwise = Lam z (rename x y e)
rename x y (App e1 e2) = App (rename x y e1) (rename x y e2)

subst e1 x1 (App e2 e3) = App (subst e1 x1 e2) (subst e1 x1 e3)
subst e1 x1 (Var x)
  | x1 == x = e1
  | otherwise = Var x
subst e1 x1 (Lam x e)
  | x1 == x = Lam x e
  | not (elem x $ fv e1) = Lam x (subst e1 x1 e)
  | otherwise = Lam xx (subst e1 x1 ee)
  where ee = rename x xx e 
        xx = x ++ x 

eval (Var x) = Var x
eval (Lam x e) = Lam x (eval e)
eval (App (Lam x m) n) = eval $ subst n x m 
-- eval (App (Lam x m) n) = eval $ subst (eval n) x (eval m)
eval (App m n) 
  | m /= evalm = App evalm n
  | otherwise = App m evaln 
  where evalm = eval m
        evaln = eval n
```

Any suggestions?
Note, I am following the definitions/conventions in Selinger's notes:

https://www.irif.fr/~mellies/mpri/mpri-ens/biblio/Selinger-Lambda-Calculus-Notes.pdf

Comment: Your `eval (App m n)` is a problem, it never removes the outermost App.

Comment: @n.m. do you mind clarifying?  aren't these of the form if M ->_beta M' then  App M N ->_beta App M' N

Comment: You *need* to do App M N ->_beta App M' N but what you are actually doing is App M N -> App M' N. Try `| m /= evalm = eval $ App evalm n`

Comment: It looks like your problem is solved already, but some general debugging advice: when I looked at the multiple lines of `Expr` output, it occurred to me that it might be easier to debug if you had a pretty-printer `pprint :: Expr -> String` so you can inspect the output more easily.

Comment: I would remove `rename x y e` and replace it with `subst (Var y) x e` -- it's simpler. Then, note that `xx = x++x` does not necessarily yield a fresh name.